# How do I ensure only my enterprise devices can sync from google drive sync or file stream

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, cloud-security

This is a bit of a long shot, I am looking for suggestions in regards to ensuring that only devices from my corporate network are able to run the google sync tool. Its imperative that my corporate files/assets cannot be synced to personal devices...

> (IE) a user on my network can simply go to their personal device, sign in on google or download google file stream (sync) and then run the sync tool. BOOM! they suddenly have all of their company files/documents on their personal device.

What would be the best way to mitigate or prevent this from occurring inside my network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Google Drive is a free cloud storage service that lets any user with a
>   Google account upload files -- documents, photos and videos -- to the
>   cloud. Any user with the necessary credentials or permissions can
>   access uploaded files from any location. Users may configure folders
>   and files uploaded to Google Drive as private (available to no one) or
>   public (available to everyone), or they may choose to share them with
>   a specific list of users.

[Google Drive security: What IT can and can't do](https://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/tip/Google-Drive-security-What-IT-can-and-cant-do)

I am not aware of any solution for Google Drive that can accomplish your goal. If a user has credentials to login to Google Drive and can access your files, they can view, download, copy, etc.